# Dynamically add cells to table rows and dynamically create table rows with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a tbody dynamically in reactjs. I have a function that creates seed data from a loop with this:

```
accounts.push(
  <tr key={i}>
  <td>{obj.type}</td>
  <td>{obj.name}</td>
  <td>{obj.balance}</td>
  <td>{obj.id}</td>
</tr>);
```

It works and i can populate rows in react with `<tbody>{accounts}</tbody>`. Now I'm trying to dynamically add `<td>`. I tried the following but it creates a string and ReactJS throws error `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>`:

```
let fields = ['type', 'name', 'balance', 'id'];

data.forEach( function(element, index) {
  let fieldsLabel = `<tr key=${++i}>`;
  fields.forEach( function(key, index) {
    fieldsLabel = fieldsLabel.concat(`<td>${element[key]}</td>`);
  });
  fieldsLabel = fieldsLabel.concat(`</tr>`);
  accounts.push(Array.from(fieldsLabel));
});
```

I'd like to do something simple like the following but it won't work because of the open `<tr>` tag:

```
    data.forEach( function(element, index) {
      let row = []
      row.push(<tr key={++i}>)
      fields.forEach( function(key, index) {
        row.push(<td>{element[key]}</td>)
      });
      row.push(</tr>)
      accounts.push(row.join(''));
    });
```

How do you dynamically push `<td>` into an array so it can be used in reactjs like `{accounts}`?

Answer (score 4):

The following will dynamically add cells to table rows and dynamically create table rows for you to use in your components.

```
class TbodyRow extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.createRow = this.createRow.bind(this);
  }

  createRow(tableRowID, data, dataOrder, cells = []) { 
    for (let i in dataOrder) {
      cells.push(<td key={i}>{data[dataOrder[i]]}</td>)
    }
    return (<tr key={tableRowID}>{cells}</tr>);
  }

  render() {
    return this.createRow(
      this.props.tbodyIdKey, 
      this.props.rowData, 
      this.props.dataOrder
    );
  }
}
```

Adding data cells (`<td>`) to a row (`<tr>`): Put this inside your method that's looping over your array of data (*i.e* `[obj, obj, obj].forEach...`):

```
let fields = ['type', 'name', 'balance', 'id'];
accounts.push(
  <TbodyRow key={obj.id}
    tbodyIdKey={obj.id} 
    rowData={obj} 
    dataOrder={fields}
  />
);
```

Then use in your tbody as requested:

```
<tbody>
  {accounts}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data.map((item,i) => {
  return(
    <tr key={++i}>
      {fields.length > 0 && fields.map((field,j) => {
         return(
            <td>{item[field]}</td>
         )
      })
    </tr>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you dynamically push  into an array so it can be used in reactjs like {accounts}?

You have the right idea but you're storing a `string` into `fieldsLabel` instead of a JSX element. Don't wrap your elements in backticks.

Don't use strings to create elements. Remember that JSX transpiles to `React.createElement` calls. If you create an element using strings then babel won't transpile that. [Refer to the reactjs documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) to learn more about how JSX works.